# How to select which data is plotted on a bar chart from a 'groupby' object in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a table created using `groupby`from Python Pandas which is called 'LikelihoodAwareness'. The table looks like this:

```
Q7                       No        Yes

AwarenessImprovement

Decrease               1.492537   0.000000

Increase              12.686567  64.925373

No change              4.477612  16.417910
```

I want to make a bar chart with the percentages (the numbers) on the y-axis, and 'Yes' 'No' on the x axis. I want the graph to be a stacked bar chart with 'Increase', 'Decrease' and 'No change' represented by different colours on the 'No', 'Yes' columns. I also want to add a legend describing which colour is 'Increase', 'Decrease', 'No change'.

I used

```
LikelihoodAwareness.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

but this plots 'Increase', 'Decrease' and 'No change' on the x-axis, and 'Yes', 'No' on the legend.

How do I make the bar chart plot the 'Yes', 'No' columns on x and the percentages for 'Increase', 'Decrease' and 'No change' as a stacked bar chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to create a DataFrame from the groupby that looks like the table you have shown, then apply on the **transposed** DataFrame.

I have created a DataFrame like your table to plot the figure.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['No']=[1.492537,12.686567,4.477612]
df['Si']=[0,64.925373,16.417910]
ax=df.T.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True,figsize=(15,15),fontsize=20)
df['index']=['Decrease','Increase','Nochange']
df.set_index('index')
ax.legend(df['index'],fontsize=20)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I spent so long trying to figure this out!

Comment: You're welcome! I have updated the figure with the legend.